# Securing RTP packets without encrypting each packets

Tags: security, encryption, sip, voip, rtp

In VoIP, I understand encrypting SIP transmission will hide the information about what codec is used. Another way is encrypting the RTP payload, So transmitting SRTP/ZRTP in network. But encrypting each packet will take quiet a lot of processing in both end. I have seen few materials about scrambling RTP (header or payload - no idea). Can anybody please suggest me if there are any other ways we can use for securing RTP, in case if it is eavesdropped, attacker will get nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe some of your concerns are addressed in the following IETF Spec - https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7201 - Options for Securing RTP Sessions

But IMO, there is a cost of security w.r.t processing and thats a given for the enhanced layer of protection. I haven't come across any other fancier ways other than encoding and decoding with some custom codec that you can build whose signal processing is proprietary to your application. But even in that case, it limits the interoperability of your application as well as still keeps it open for brute force hacking if possible.

Comment: Excellent reply Rajesh.